# Snowsql disconnects after keystroke

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I installed it on my Macbook pro today as I need to run a few scripts from the command line. I put my connection settings in the config file and that's it.

When I connect, I get this screen
[image]

I can see I'm successfully connected as my username to my warehouse in the right database and schema. But on the first keystroke, this is what happens

[image]

```
(no warehouse)@(no database).(no schema)
```

I seem to lose connection to my warehouse, database and schema all at once. When I run the command to use my warehouse, it fails with this error

[image]

Any Snowflake command will throw the same error.

I get the same issue when I disable my config file and connect from the command line.

What am I missing here?

Comment: do you have a warehouse named `DBT_WAREHOUSE` ? And do you have access to it ? can ou confirm from UI?

Comment: Yes, I do have such a warehouse and I do have access to it from the UI.

Comment: Check if the user and the role you use in UI and can use the desired warehouse, db, schema  are the same as in SnowSQL config.

Comment: They're the same.

Comment: @CB Can you enable logging on SnowSQL and check the log once you reproduce the issue?

Comment: can you use without quotes `use warehouse dbt_warehouse` ?

Comment: Tried without quotes. And lowercase. Problem remains.

Comment: @Sergiu Log shows no errors. However, it shows `INFO     connection:568  - No async queries seem to be running, deleting session` and `snowflake.cli.sqlexecute DEBUG     sqlexecute:373  - closing connections` several times.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to reproduce the problem by issuing non-existing warehouse, db and schema in my connection:

[image]

It could be that you're connecting using a warehouse, etc. that are not active/valid in your session upon logon. You have to make sure that the role active in your session have access to the warehouse, etc. To do that, the following checks might help:

1. Logon to Web UI and check your current_role

   select current_role();
2. While using that role, verify that you can access the warehouse and the schema

   show warehouses like '<warehouse_name>';

   show schemas like '<schema_name>' in database <db_name>;

Note that db_name is not enclosed in quotes. Both queries should return a result.

3. Upon confirming, make sure that the verified role is active upon connecting.

   snowsql -a <account> -u <user> -r <role> -w <warhouse> -d <db> -s <schema>

Comment: My warehouse does exist. So does my role, db and schema. I set them in my config file. The one thing to note is that my userid's default role is PUBLIC, which has no permissions basically. I need to set it to the role my DBA created to enable my permissions.